# Can I slice a list like numpy?

Tags: python, list, numpy

If I use numpy, than I can slice an array as follows:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(A[np.asarray([1, 3])])
```

Then the output is `[2 4]`.
I wonder if I can do the same operation without using numpy, **when A is just a list**.

Comment: .... `A[[1,3]]`?

Comment: @Divakar Sorry for misunderstanding. I edited the question to specify that A is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just a little more typing, using a *list comprehension*:

```
print([A[n] for n in [1, 3]])
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be a good way. How fast a list comprehension? I wonder which one is faster between yours and the numpy way.

Comment: List comprehensions are fast-- much faster than appending elements to a list one by one, for example. Whether to use numpy or ordinary lists really, really depends on your use case, not on this single detail of the syntax. You'll need to measure performance yourself, there is no blanket answer.

Comment: @alexis I wouldn't say "much faster", but "marginally faster". Not orders of magnitude faster, like a numpy array

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Could you more specific what do you mean by "like a numpy array"?

Comment: I think it means that if you can use numpy, it will in general be faster than python lists. That's the whole purpose of numpy.

Comment: Leaving numpy aside, are you sure about that @juanpa? In my experience, a loop like `for x in list_a: list_b.append(x)` is more than marginally slower than a comprehension.

Comment: Here's what I mean exactly: https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/d713c3f9bf9a7d3da84c6968f86e06bd so "marginal" as in less than numpy, as in, you are still using the same units of time. And the more complicated what you are doing inside the list comprehension becomes, the differences shrink dramatically. Essentially, list comprehensions optimize appending.

Comment: Note, I updated the gist with an additional example, showing how for small lists, the differences are practically gone, because a list-comprehension creates a function object underneath the hood, which has some overhead.

Comment: @juanpa, thanks for the demo. I admit that the difference is smaller than I expected, but for small datasets all of this is beside the point-- only large lists matter (and 1000 elements is rather on the low side of "large"). Of course the difference disappears when you make the test set so small-- what's being tested will take only a fraction of the total time.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't. You can *slice* a pure python list. However, this is not slicing. If you try that on a list, you get

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

This is supported by numpy arrays because they have a different implementation of the `__get__` method. Nothing you can do about it, except from subclassing the `list` class yourself (which you shouldn't really, the numpy implementation is optimized for such operations).